# determine file type c

Tags: c++, webserver

I am trying to write a client/server program in C++ with Visual Studio 2008. So far the project runs does the following:

Run the webserver on cmd prompt - webserver 8080
open web browser - localhost 8080
to open local html file - localhost:8080/demo.html

But now... let's say the client requests for a gif file, then the server should send gif file.
client request for txt file, then the server should send .txt file. Similarly for .html and .xbm files.

I don't know how to do it.. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX systems you'd use the `file` command: it uses a set of known "magic number" which are used to identify different file types. anda few heuristics to address the remaining files. Most file formats have some sort of identifier embedded, often in the first couple of bytes. Especially text files normally don't have a magic number but use only printable characters instead (with UTF8 and UTF16 being popular, classifying text files became a bit harder).

Once the file type is determined, you'd just set ghe corresponding HTTP header(s).

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention -- I am trying this on Win 8.

Comment: @user1340561: I realized that you are using Windows giving that you are using VS 2008. However, the approach does work on Windows, too, although I don't think that something like `file` immediately ships with Windows but it should be part, e.g., of cygwin.

Comment: The `file` utility [is available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) as well. It's worth saying that determining a file's type, without _trusting_ information like the extension, is very difficult at best. The source code of that utility should give you an idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

okay, because we're in the same class, I'll give you a clue :)

In the header part, put some if-else like this:

```
if(strcmp(type,"html")==0){
  (void) sprintf(buff,"Content-Type:text/html\r\n");
  (void) send(conn,buff,strlen(buff),0);
}

else if(strcmp(type,"gif")==0){
  (void) sprintf(buff,"Content-Type:image/gif\r\n");
  (void) send(conn,buff,strlen(buff),0);
}
```

Got it? And by the way, you need to get the extension (check path using `endsWith` function), compare the extension with file type then give out the right header. Test it with gif file :) I have it works already :) Going to submit now. Remember to vote up for me :)

Comment: Still can't get it to work.. gives an error C2065: 'type': undeclared identifier.

Comment: `undeclared identifier` means you haven't declare the variable. It must be declared at the beginning.